# Noms propres : Comment détermine-t-on leur genre ?

Tags: articles, genre, noms-propres

Exemples:

> Voulez-vous la nourriture de la Deli
>   Voulez-vous la nourriture de la Saint-Jean Deli

(en anglais: "St. John Deli")
C'est un restaurant. Premier du sandwich á la viande et le fromage.

Dois-je remplacer "de la" par "du"?

Comment puis-je déterminer la réponse à cette question pour les futurs noms propres?

Comment: Tout dépend de ce qu'est *St. John Deli*.  Est-ce que par Deli tu veux dire *delicatessen* ? Si oui pourquoi ce « D » majuscule qui implique que Deli est un nom propre ? Si c'est bien ce que je pense tu ne pourras pas garder *deli* en français. Il te faudra choisir le bon mot en français. Et l'article « le » ou « la » sera déterminé parle choix de ce mot. Si *St. John Deli* est le nom propre complet alors il faut savoir quel genre d'établissement c'est. Restaurant (le), brasserie (la), etc...

Comment: @Laure, ne devrais tu pas écrire ces réponses dans les... réponses? Pour qui que ce soit passant avec une recherche pourra plus facilement trouver la réponse à la question ce cette façon, non?

Comment: @Sifu j'ai pas répondu. Je demandais au PO de donner plus de précision sur son emploi de *Deli* avec une majuscule. Je sais bien qu'en anglais on met des majuscules un peu partout dans les noms et toujours dans les titres, et si c'était *St John's Deli* il n'y aurait pas eu ambiguïté non plus mais là... hmm

Comment: @Laure, mais en même temps tu as répondu à toutes les possibilités ou nuances que la question peut porter. Y-a-t'il d'autres réponses possible ou d'autres nuances à sa question?

Comment: Still need time to translate all these helpful looking answers.

Comment: Just say if you need anything put into English.

Answer (score 4):

Que *Le Saint Jean* soit un **café** ou une **brasserie**, comme Jean est un nom masculin on dira :

> Je vais manger au Saint Jean

Que *La Coupole* soit un café ou une brasserie, on dira :

> Je vais à La Coupole.

Mais :

> Je vais à la brasserie le Saint Jean (La Coupole).
>    Je vais au restaurant le Saint Jean (La Coupole).

*Le Délicatessen* est un **bistrot brasserie** :

> Je vais manger au Délicatessen<sup>1</sup>.

Passons au cas de **la charcuterie** *Adriano*.  ([**la** charcuterie](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/charcuterie))

> Veux-tu de la nourriture de la charcuterie Adriano ?

Et au cas **du traiteur** Adriano. ([**le** traiteur](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/traiteur))

> Veux-tu de la nourriture du traiteur Adriano ?

Mais je peux dire aussi :

> Veux-tu de la nourriture de chez Adriano ?

Je pense que c'est cette dernière formulation qui serait chez moi la plus spontanée.

Et comme je sais que **la charcuterie traiteur** *Adriano* est tenue par un italien, je pourrais dire :

> Veux-tu de la nourriture de chez l'italien ? Ou préfères-tu qu'on aille chez le grec ?

Dans le cas du bistrot brasserie *Le Délicatessen*, « Délicatessen » est un nom propre, malgré la présence de l'article défini devant (comme on pourrait dire *Le Saint-Jean*), bien sûr emprunté à l'américain. En français l'équivalent de ce que les américains appellent  *deli* c'est un traiteur, ou une épicerie-traiteur<sup>1</sup>.

En français tu pourrais dire :

> Veux-tu de la nourriture de chez Saint-Jean ?

En franglais je dirais :

> Veux-tu de la nourriture du deli ?

C'est je pense ce que je dirais spontanément, donc en le traitant comme un nom masculin.

Mais on peut aussi dire :

> Veux-tu de la nourriture de la deli ?

Si on pense que c'est une épicerie, ce serait logique. On peut improviser dans la mesure où le franglais n'est pas standardisé.

<sup>1. Ça existe, mais pas de pub, je ne dirai pas où c'est.</sup>
<sup>2. La différence entre un épicier et un traiteur ce sera pour une autre question.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Nous sommes ici dans le cas d'une contraction où le nom est sous-entendu et n'est donc pas prononcé ou écrit. Dire que l'on veut "*la nourriture du St. John Deli*" signifie que l'on veut "*la nourriture du* [restaurant] *St. John Deli*" Le genre de l'article à utiliser est donc celui du nom qui est sous-entendu (restaurant, brasserie, café... je ne connais pas le type d'établissement du St. John Deli). Étant donné qu'il s'agit d'un restaurant, nous dirons donc "*la nourriture du restaurant St. John Deli*" ou, en contractant, "*la nourriture du St. John Deli*".

Comment: C'est un restaurant. Premier du sandwich á la viande et le fromage.